# SQL Cumulative Sum by Group by time condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have a table with columns **dummy_id**, **date_registered**, **item_id**, **quantity**, **price**, like this:

| dummy_id | date_registered | item_id | quantity | price | my_cumulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2013-07-01 | 100 | 10 | 34.5 | 10 |
| 2 | 2013-07-01 | 145 | 8 | 2.3 | 8 |
| 3 | 2013-07-11 | 100 | 20 | 34.5 | 30 |
| 4 | 2013-07-23 | 100 | 15 | 34.5 | 45 |
| 5 | 2013-07-24 | 145 | 10 | 34.5 | 18 |

And if I want to calculate column **my_cumulative** which contains the cumulative totals of each item_id order by date_registered I use this code:

```sql
select dummy_id, date_registered, item_id, quantity, price,
       sum(quantity) over (partition by item_id order by date_registered) as cumulative
from table t;
```

And it works well. But what if I now want to **my_cumulative** column for each row to count only orders from the last month? (calculate the sum of the quantity only for rows where the date_register column is less than the current one, no more than a month)

Is there any way to do this in sql? (prefer postgresql)

Comment: Please define what you mean by "last month".  It is not clear.

Comment: For a row with item_id=100 and date_registered=2013-07-23, the my_cumulative column contains the total quantity of orders since 2013-06-23, and not from the beginning of the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want cumulative quantities for the current month -- which is what I suspect you want, then change the `partition by`:

```
select dummy_id, date_registered, item_id, quantity, price,
       sum(quantity) over (partition by item_id, date_trunc('month', date_registered) order by date_registered) as cumulative
from table t;
```

If you really want the last month, then use a range window frame with interval:

```
select dummy_id, date_registered, item_id, quantity, price,
       sum(quantity) over (partition by item_id
                           order by date_registered
                           range between interval '1 month' preceding and current row
                          ) as cumulative
from table t;
```

The first seems much more useful to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not exactly what I need. In your solution, time intervals are specified by calendar months and do not overlap with each other. But I need each row to contain the total quantity for the last 30 days relative to it. That is, the row with the date 2013-07-23 contained the total quantity starting from 2013-06-23, and the row with the date 2013-07-11 contained the total quantity starting from 2013-06-11

Comment: is there such a possibility in sql?

Comment: @ilyazyulyaev . . . Try the second.  I accidentally left the `date_trunc()` in the `partition by`.  I removed it.